# Working with Changing Named Ranges Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a fairly lengthy macro in Excel VBA. I want to use named ranges instead of specifying it in the macro. This macro is intended for long-term use. What happens if the range shifts by another user? How can I adjust my code so my named ranges can accommodate for changing positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (personally) hate named ranges. Especially, when you are copying or pasting sheets / ranges from one file to another you always end up with dead-references or copied over named ranges which do not work anymore or got renamed (because they existed already in that file).

My solution to this is one of the following two:

(1) I dedicate a certain part (or even module) in the VBA to declaring my ranges in global variables. This is very similar to the `Dim` of all variables at the beginning of each sub.

```
'*********************************************************
'** Declaring all ranges and where to find which data
'*********************************************************

Dim rngNamedRangeName As Range

Sub SetupAllGlobalVariables()

Set rngNamedRangeName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C10")

End Sub

'*********************************************************
'** After that all your normal subs follow and whenever
'** necessary you can call the above to get your ranges
'*********************************************************

Sub ExampleCodeToFormatYourRanges()

Call SetupAllGlobalVariables

With rngNamedRangeName
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End With

End Sub
```

(2) Yet, my preferred second solution is to have a separate `very hidden` sheet where I reference / link all the ranges (which are important to me) again. So, basically, I have in this separate sheet all the "important" data again. This would be your named ranges. But nobody is allowed to touch this sheet (that's why its **very** hidden). If any of your ranges get shifted or changed then it is easy to re-link the ranges on this hidden sheet with the other sheets again. Yet, on the hidden sheet all data is still in the same spot and allows you to hard-code all ranges in your VBA (taken from the hidden sheet only).

Even non-VBA programmers can normally fix such things with the second method. With the first method you'll probably always need someone with VBA skills to fix it.

<sub>Note, the above is not the one and only solution nor might it be the best solution. But I can certainly say that this has proven to be a usable solution  even for larger corporations.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But your second solution may sacrifice usability for multiple users and the portability of the macro and spreadsheet.  When you have hidden spreadsheet it will eventually drift out of memory.

Comment: At some point you have to tell VBA where to find the data and until you don't put it on a structured database server (SQL) you have to hard-code the references at some point somewhere. So, now you are given three options and you can evaluate them and experiment with them as much as you wish. I (personally) have done so for a long time and came to the above conclusions. Yet, different setups / parameters might lead to different conclusions. So, have fun trying them all out and comparing them. Possibly someone can even add another practicable solution.